# Disable browser authentication dialog in spring security

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am using spring security 4, for some reason after I finish authentication with my login page I get browser authentication dialog which force me to authenticate again.

this is my security configuration:

```
    http.antMatcher("/test")
            .httpBasic()
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/index.html", "/login.html", "/", "/scripts/**",
                    "/bower_components/**", "/styles/**", "/views/**",
                    "/login", "/api/user/*").permitAll().anyRequest()
            .authenticated().and().logout().logoutUrl("/api/logout").and()
            .csrf().csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository()).and()
            .addFilterAfter(csrfHeaderFilter(), CsrfFilter.class);
```

Comment: Remove `httpBasic()`.

Comment: Hi. This not helps, the dialog still exist

Comment: Then you have something else that triggers basic or digest authentication.

Comment: What else can trigger it ?

Comment: Something in your configuration, you only posted a snippet. Or something in your infrastructure... There is something that is sending a 401 with a BASIC (or DIGEST) header else you wouldn't get the popup.

Answer (score 16):

The authentication popup is caused by the response header `WWW-Authenticate: Basic`, which is set by [BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.4.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/www/BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint.html).

Use a custom `AuthenticationEntryPoint` that doesn't set `WWW-Authenticate: Basic`:

```
public class NoPopupBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
        AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException, ServletException {
    
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, authException.getMessage());
    }

}
```

Add the custom authentication entry point to the security configuration (order is important):

```
http
    .httpBasic()
    .authenticationEntryPoint(new NoPopupBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint())
```

Comment: Nice one. that has helped me a lot.

Answer (score 5):

In WebFlux it's not enough to just disable httpBasic. There is an ExceptionTranslationWebFilter that uses HttpBasicServerAuthenticationEntryPoint by default, causing such behavior. To disable it you should install another ServerAuthenticationEntryPoint, for example:

```
http.exceptionHandling()
    .authenticationEntryPoint(HttpStatusServerEntryPoint(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN))
    .
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `formLogin()` instead of `httpBasic()`. Refactoring your config to this:

```
http
   .antMatcher("/test")
   .authorizeRequests()
   .antMatchers("/index.html", "/login.html", "/", "/scripts/**",
       "/bower_components/**", "/styles/**", "/views/**",
       "/login", "/api/user/*").permitAll()
   .anyRequest().authenticated()
   .and().formLogin().loginPage("/your_login_page_here").permitAll()
   .and().logout().logoutUrl("/api/logout").and()
   .csrf().csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository()).and()
   .addFilterAfter(csrfHeaderFilter(), CsrfFilter.class);
```

In case `/login.html` is your login page, you would want to remove it from one of the `permitAll()` locations.